# Google Contacts API HTTP server responses are not correct

Tags: google-contacts-api

We are using Contacts API in one of our products to synchronize Contacts. Starting from this week we noticed that HTTP responds are different quite often, and not correct according to documentation here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts

It appears that there seem to be two separate types of servers, one of which sends a 200 OK status and another which sends a 201 Created status. In addition, the 200 response always responds with multi-line XML with double quotes, while the 201 always sends it on a single line with single quotes. The two also serve different headers. The JSON responses suffer from similar issues.

We already had this issue previously several months ago, but it disappeared in about 24 hours. Right now I think it's already happening starting from June 19.

Any thoughts how this can be avoided? Or should we already plan redevelopment of our code to support 2 different types of responses?

Thank you,
Denis

Comment: Are you using any of the availables SDK or just raw http?

Comment: No, we are using raw http from C++ code.